# Adding html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm trying to add specific html line to specific place with javascript code.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Map</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

      <!--<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>-->  <!--Add this line to here with js-->

  </ion-content>
```

I tried `document.getelementbyid.inner/outerhtml` and `document.write` but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Post what you tried, even if it didn’t work.

Comment: javascript is case sensitive, so probablly `document.getElementById('elementid').innerHTML`

Comment: If you literally used `document.getelementbyid` you would have received console errors. Check documentation for [**getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and similar and post your code that doesn't work in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any id or class there. So Instead Try using Tag name

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ion-content")[0].innerHTML = '<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>';
```

Comment: @rektandlove I tried my code in my sytem and it is working perfectly. 
Can you let me know what Error are you getting while executing my code??
Check my Edited Code

Comment: thanks your code is working i guess but maybe im trying to solve my problem in a wrong way.can you check this topic: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/leaflet-switching-tabs-map-container-is-already-initialized/108124     im trying to delete map div when i leave the map tap and initialize it when i load my map tab again.but seems like its not working.

Comment: If my code works that means it is solution for your question, why give -ve points againts it.

Anyway in your code "<ion-content padding>" pls add ID to it if you strictly want to use 

     "document.getElementbyid"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
document.querySelector("ion-content" ).innerHTML = "<a style='color: red'> ASD</a>" ;
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Map</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.40.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

      <!--<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>-->  <!--Add this line to here with js-->

  </ion-content>
```